# Elastic seacrh .net returning null values

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Elastic search when used in .Net returns the document count is correct but the values inside the object is null for all documents

```
var searchResponse = eClient.Search<elasticdocument>(s => s
                                    .Query(q => q
                                    .MatchAll()
                                    ));
```

`searchResponse.document.count = 2` //its correct

Values inside the model elasticdocument (usernam = null,age=null)

but the data is present when checked via postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Akf.png)

Comment: You meant you are getting the 2 objects but the values inside them is null ?

Comment: Please make the explaination of the problem more clear in the question

Comment: Its not clear whether document itself or fields inside document are coming as null. It would be great if you elaborate more. Few things to try: #1 see if you can pass source param in the lamda expression. #2 In the searchResponse, check inside `Hits` to see if you are getting the data there.

Comment: Could it be that the elasticdocument class could not be mapped to the elastic index correctly? Can you show the elasticdocument definition and the index definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set:

```
settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);
```

Example:

```
public static void AddElasticsearch(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, bool configureDefaultQuery = true)
{
    var defaultIndex = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:defaultIndex"];
    var basicAuthUser = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:username"];
    var basicAuthPassword = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:password"];

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:uri"]));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultIndex))
        settings = settings.DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(basicAuthUser) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(basicAuthPassword))
        settings = settings.BasicAuthentication(basicAuthUser, basicAuthPassword);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/field-inference.html

Answer (score -1):

Set connectionSettings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(x => x.ToLower()); in your code

The below code worked for me:

```
            var nodes = new Uri[] { new Uri(CommonCalls.ElasticSearchUrl) };

            var connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DisableDirectStreaming();
            connectionSettings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(x => x.ToLower());
            var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(CommonCalls.IndexName));
```